# dictionary requires a model item of type 'Projectname.Sp name'

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am doing a sample where i require stored procedure result have to be displayed in view(created strongly typed view by choosing details in dropdown).from service i am getting result in this format

`[{"studentID":1,"studentName":"Suja","StudentDepaertment":"Economics"}]`
but i get error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[StudentForm.sp_join_details_Result]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'StudentForm.sp_join_details_Result'.

Homecontroller.cs

```
   public ActionResult Details(string name)
    {
        studentEntities data = new studentEntities();
        List<sp_join_details_Result> model = null;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:99991/");
        var response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("api/Details?name={0}", name)).Result;
        var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseBody.Wait();
        var productString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sp_join_details_Result>>(responseBody.Result);
        return View(productString);
      }
```

Details.cshtml

```
 @model EmployAppraisalForm.sp_join_details_Result

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
 }

 <h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
<legend>sp_join_details_Result</legend>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.studentID)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.studentID)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.studentName)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.studentName)
</div>
</fieldset>
```

I know i have to covert the response of service to result that could be displayed in view,to which i should convert ?Please help me in this.....

Comment: The message is self explanatory - your returning a collection of `sp_join_details_Result` to a view which expects a single `sp_join_details_Result` object. Use `.FirstOrDefault()` to return a single object or change the view to `@model List<sp_join_details_Result>` and loop through the items to display them.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  thanks it worked ,i added .FirstorDefault() to my result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Details()` method is returning `List<sp_join_details_Result>` to a view which expects a single `sp_join_details_Result` object.

If you want to display a single object, then change the return statement to

```
return View(productString.FirstOrDefault());
```

Alternatively, if your wanting to display a collection of objects, change the view to

```
@model List<sp_join_details_Result>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    ....
```